# Can I change the item size to fit the Android phone screen size and apply it?

Tags: android, android-adapter, screen-size, gridlayoutmanager

I am an Android app developer. While providing the user with a screen where they can select various emojis, the following picture occurred.

[image]

I coded it to show 8 per line through GridLayoutManager.

```
override fun onCrateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
    ...
    binding.recycler.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(mContext, 8)
    binding.recycler.setHasFixedSize(true)
    binding.recycler.adapter = EmojiAdapter(mContext, emojis)
}
```

`EmojiAdapter` is:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: EmojiViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val metrics = context.resources.dsiplayMetrics
    holder.emojiText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, metrics.widthPixels / 30f)
}
```

I put an emoji in the `TextView` and put the code to adjust the `textsize`. But the result was the same as the picture above... How do I adjust the textSize so that it is exactly 8 equal to the width of the screen?

### **[EDIT]**

change width => match_parent

[image]

Comment: in adapter put textView widht match_parent

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As you said I set the width of the ```TextView``` to ```match_parent``` in the adpater and another problem occurred. Like the picture attached above, the emoticons are too small to use. Is there any other way to change the size of the emoticons more fluidly to fit the screen size?

Comment: can you show where you are seeting the emoj and also and emoj data

Comment: Emoticons are stored in a ```string array``` by creating a separate ```class```.

Comment: how you set emoj in text View its setting in backround or liek tesxtView.stText